# How do I properly use channels inside a parallelized Go test?

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, parallel-processing, channel

I'm experimenting with parallel subtests, and I'm hitting a goroutine deadlock error. Assuming that `tt` is a table test with valid values, and `LastIndex` is the function being tested, the following code runs all the tests, but errors out:

```
for _, tt := range tests {
    tt := tt
    t.Run("foo", func(t *testing.T) {
        t.Parallel()
        done := make(chan bool)
        for {
            select {
            case <-done:
                return
            case <-time.After(time.Second):
                if got := LastIndex(tt.list, tt.x); got != tt.want {
                    t.Fatalf("LastIndex(%v, %v) = %v, want %v", tt.list, tt.x, got, tt.want)
                } else {
                    done <- true
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Specifically: `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`

The error implies that the supertest is still waiting on results from these subtests, but shouldn't `return` and `t.Fatalf()` have exited them? The Go docs say that channels don't necessarily need to be closed, but I tried closing them anyway, and it still didn't work. I also tried to create the channel outside the subtest scope, inside the range iteration, and defer closing it with a `t.Cleanup()`, but that didn't work either.

Full code here: https://play.golang.org/p/1ujIIl7pjY9 *Not all tests pass, this is intentional*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `t.Run` call runs the test function in a separate goroutine and waits until it returns. The for-loop in the test writes to the `done` channel if a test is successful, however there are no other goroutines reading from the `done` channel, hence the deadlock.

Instead of writing to the `done` channel, you can close it. That will be detected next time around. However note that you are running only one goroutine, there is no concurrency here.

Comment: Yes, edited the question to add the missing `t.Parallel()` call per run. Replacing the send with a close worked.